# animation-direction: reverse skipping from start frame to end frame

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to implement an expanding menu, and want to polish it up with some CSS3 animation. I have it working nicely using two separate classes + keyframe rules for expanding and collapsing. However, since the animations are the same, just reversed, I'd like to be able to just add `animation-direction: reverse;` to one of the two controlling classes.

This not only doesn't work, but it breaks the animation in *both* directions. Instead of sliding in and out, it seems to just skip from start to end (and/or skip animating and go directly to the end state). What's wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/7g2Jg/6/

Update: Actually, `reverse` breaks the slide effect entirely in Chrome (even using `-webkit` prefix) and IE10. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction#Browser_compatibility) says it should work.

Comment: The problem is that just changing the animation-direction won't **replay** the animation. You are just changing one animation property, but the animation has played, has ended, and so it won't play again. When you change animations, then every time the animation plays.

Comment: In the first case (two animations), alternating the styles triggers the animation. Does the second case (shared animation) not trigger on a style change because the browser considers the animation run for class2 because it ran for and is shared with class1? I just tried removing _all_ classes on-click and re-adding the desired one, but the second case still fails. How is it different from the first?

Comment: The animation ran for the element, not for the class. If you don't change the animation-name, it's the same animation. To remove and add the animation in the same function call won't work because the browser has to render without the animation before adding the new class. Do it delayed and it works. See http://jsfiddle.net/7g2Jg/7/

Comment: So, it's just a race condition? The browser has to have its millisecond (or less) to render the item after `removeClass` before it can render it again after `addClass`? Post that as an answer, please. (It still seems broken at some level, but this is, at least, a workaround.)